# Cloning Queue Without Remove Elements From Original Queue [Java]

Tags: java, queue

I am trying to cloning a Queue without removing elements from the original queue.
I implemented a Queue class with my own Node class (I'm only showing the Queue class with only specific functions):

```
public class Queue<T> 
{
    private Node<T> first;
    private Node<T> last;

    public Queue()
    {
        this.first = null;
        this.last = null;
    }
    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return this.first == null;
    }

    public void insert(T x)
    {
        if (this.last == null)
        {
            this.last = new Node<T>(x);
            this.first = this.last;
        }
        else
        {
            this.last.setNext(new Node<T>(x));
            this.last = this.last.getNext();
        }
    }
    public T remove()
    {
        T res = this.first.getInfo();
        this.first = this.first.getNext();
        if (this.first == null)
            this.last = null;
        return res;

    }
}
```

The way I tried to clone:

```
public static Queue<Integer> cloneQueue(Queue<Integer> q)
    {
        Queue<Integer> q1 = new Queue<Integer>();
        Queue<Integer> pos = q;
        while (!pos.isEmpty())
        {
            q1.insert(pos.remove());
        }
        return q1;
    }
```

My problem with the cloning function is the comparing of the same pointer in that line:

```
Queue<Integer> pos = q;
```

How can I solve the problem without affecting the original queue from the main function?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason for your own Queue implementation?
You may simply use the standard Java implementation. If you want to have your own interface, you can always wrap a [java.util.Queue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) in your own Queue.

```
public class Queue<T> {
    private java.util.Deque<T> queue = new ArrayDeque<>();

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return this.queue.isEmpty();
    }

    public void insert(T x) {
        this.queue.offerLast(x);
    }

    public T remove() {
        return this.queue.poll();
    }

    public static <T> Queue<T> cloneQueue(Queue<T> q) {
        Queue<T> clone = new Queue<T>();
        clone.queue = new ArrayDeque<T>(q.queue);
        return clone;
    }
}
```